# Include element in array if is not present in other array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this array:

```
let idsClass = [1,2]
```

and i have this other array:

```
let idsQuiz = [{id: 1}]
```

I need to know the id numbers that have in `idsClass` that is missing in `idsQuiz`.

So, i need an new array containing this elements, for this example, this is the correct output:

`[2]`

I tryed something like:

```
 idsClass.forEach(item => { if (!idsQuizz.includes({id:item})) { console.log('dont find this: ' + item) } })
```

But my console is printing the two elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Comment: When I copy-paste your code and run it, the value of `idsQuiz` is `[1,2]`

Comment: sorry i forgot to specify that the second array is an array of object

Comment: So is the expected output `[1,2]` or `[{id: 1},{id: 2}]`?

Comment: this problem is very poorly defined. The title says to include elements in the array if it's *not* in the other array, yet the question says to put in the array *all* elements from the other array. The expected output is integers, yet the starting array is objects. This is certainly being overcomplicated.

Comment: Some more sample input/output data would help clarify the problem I think.

Comment: @Klaycon you are right, i will edit with more informations

Comment: @Klaycon please check my updte, i put the correct informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient method, but I think this way is easy to understand:

```js
let idsClass = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let idsQuiz = [{id: 1},{id: 4}];

let result = idsClass.filter(n => !idsQuiz.some(o => o.id == n));

console.log(result);
```

Simply use a `filter()` on the `idsClass`. `filter` will return a new array with only the elements that pass the inner function. In this case, it only returns elements that *aren't* in the `idsQuiz`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) built-in function to check existence.

```js
let idsClass = [1,2];


let idsQuiz = [{id: 1}];

idsClass.forEach(item => {
  if (idsQuiz.filter(e => e.id === item).length === 0) {
    idsQuiz.push({id: item});
  }
});

console.log(idsQuiz); // output is [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]
```

Comment: There's a way to make this work if the second array is an array of object? My second element is an array of object and i try:   idsClass.forEach(item => {
   if (!idsQuizz.includes({id:item})) {
     console.log('dont find this: ' + item)
  }
 })

but is returning the two elements

Comment: Yes, there is. Check it's key with includes function.
if (! idsQuiz.includes(item.id)) {

Comment: if i put this way, item.id is undefined, i need to compare the key of the idsQuiz.id

Comment: You could use filter function in case.

Answer (score 2):

basic solution

```
let idsClass = [1,2,2,4,5,6];
let idsQuiz = [1,4];
for(let i=0;i<idsClass.length;i++){
    let j=0;
    for(;j<idsQuiz.length;j++){
        if(idsClass[i] === idsQuiz[j]){
            break;
        }
    }
    if(j === idsQuiz.length) {
        idsQuiz.push(idsClass[i]);
    }
}
console.log(idsQuiz);
```

solution using inbuilt methods

```
let idsClass = [1,2,2,4,5,6];
let idsQuiz = [1,4];

// Adds all elements of idsClass into idsQuiz. may contain duplicates
idsQuiz.push(...idsClass);

//Removes duplicates from idsQuiz
idsQuiz = idsQuiz.filter((val,index,self) => self.indexOf(val) === index);
console.log(idsQuiz);
```

your code adds element into idsQuiz whenever an element in idsClass doesn't match with an element in idsQuiz. Instead, iterate through whole idsQuiz list and then add if it doesn't exist for each idsClass element.

idsClass = [1,2,3]
idsQuiz = [1]

i = 0, j=0 (no element is added in idsQuiz)
i=1, j=0 (2 is added in idsQuiz)
i=1, j=1 (no element is added in idsQuiz)
i=2, j=0 (3 is added in idsQuiz)
i=2, j=1 (3 is added in idsQuiz)
i=2, j=2 (no element is added in idsQuiz)
i=2, j=3 (no element is added in idsQuiz)